# Suggestions of what to do during Roof Replacement

Tags: insulation, roof, roofing, sealing, replacement

I'm a fairly new homeowner of an older house who's learning to be handy and last month we had a leak in our roof. We knew coming into the home that we were going to have to replace the roof, so this really kicked that into motion. We already found a company to do everything, but I have a couple of questions:

1. Anything I should try and do/ensure while the roof is off? I'm really trying to take advantage of this since it's probably a once-in-a-home opportunity. Here's some of the things I'm doing and have considered:

   - Proper attic venting as ours is horrible right now (doing ridge vent + edge vent due to hip roof)
   - Moving bathroom exhaust fans closer to bathrooms to reduce hose length
   - Replacing skylight
   - Adding two solar tubes
   - Air sealing the drywall/penetrations along the top plate
   - Air sealing and adding insulation in some difficult/awkward to reach areas
   - Looked into adding overhangs + soffit vents (for better protection + air flow), but was cost prohibitive
2. Originally, the house didn't have a porch in the front. Previous owners added a porch, and to cover it they just built a new roof segment above of the existing roof but extending over the porch. A picture: [image]
   The leak we got highlighted a visibility issue - it was actually a double roof leak:

   - It leaked through our exterior roof somewhere (we don't know where yet for sure)
   - It also leaked through the interior roof, eventually hitting the drywall ceiling.

My current plan is to ask the roofer to remove the boards/shingles of the interior roof to open things up so we have visbility. Does this seem like a good idea or will this lead to structural problems?

Comment: Your question covers a lot of ground and is somewhat open-ended, making it a bit off topic. We expect a more specific question. You finish with a fairly specific question but without providing enough information for us to answer--sheathing removal is a structural change. I suggest breaking this up and posting specific questions about each topic as you see fit.

Comment: It is common (and fairly low-risk) to simply cut an access port in the old roof, though. A 2 ft. by 4 ft. opening between rafters should do for most purposes.

Comment: All the questions you have should be asked of the roofing contractor.  Ask and come to an agreement with costs outlined, before the contract is signed.  Don't wait and add things later as this will add extra cost if the roofer agrees to do them at all.

Comment: A common complaint around here is that the contractor didn't flatten the roof. If there are sagging areas that you want fixed, then be sure to use your words with potential contractors.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the hidden roof will remove some weight. That's a good thing. Unfortunately, the old roof could be serving an important structural purpose.

When the wind blows against the gable end sides of your house, that load must find its way into the house's foundation. "Wall bracing" is how the load typically travels from up high down to the foundation elevation, but roof and ceiling "diaphragms" are how the load typically travels out to the wall bracing. Theoretically your porch could have incorporated wall bracing that works with the new roof to make the old roof and old wall bracing totally redundant (I'm skeptical). Theoretically the ceiling diaphragm and some bracing in the attic could circumvent the old roof and make it totally useless (more likely, but I'm still skeptical).

You can strip roofing material from the old subroof. The purpose of that would be to prevent rafters from sagging under the weight. Such sagging could impact the exposed roof ridge, where the effort might not be wasted.

With an old house I would get a licensed engineer on the hook for any damage that results from removing the old subroof. Sounds risky.